# How to access error message of Form in react-hook-form with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

## Tech Stack

1. React v17.x
2. [React-Hook-Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) v7.x
3. Typescript v4.4.x

## Background

I made a small form with React-Hook-Form like below.

```
type PuzzleMessageFormValue = {
  puzzleMessage: string;
};

export default function PuzzleSettingModal() {
  const puzzleMessageForm = useForm<PuzzleMessageFormValue>();
  return (
    <div
      className={classNames('invalid-feedback', {
        'd-block':
          puzzleMessageForm.formState.errors.hasOwnProperty('puzzleMessage'),
      })}
    >
      {puzzleMessageForm.formState.errors.hasOwnProperty('puzzleMessage') &&
        puzzleMessageForm.formState.errors.puzzleMessage?.message}
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Problem

I want to get error message from `puzzleMessageForm` and check the `puzzleMessage` field has error more neatly.

I know that this code is possible.

```
type PuzzleMessageFormValue = {
  puzzleMessage: string;
};

export default function PuzzleSettingModal() {
  const {
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<PuzzleMessageFormValue>();

  return (
    <div
      className={classNames('invalid-feedback', {
        'd-block': errors.hasOwnProperty('puzzleMessage'),
      })}
    >
      {errors.hasOwnProperty('puzzleMessage') && errors.puzzleMessage?.message}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But, I want to use `puzzleMessageForm` because there are many other forms in this component.

So, is there any good(short) solution to get error & error message from `puzzleMessageForm` with typescript?